# Prove that exist a base for a invariant subspace $U$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vectorial space of dimension $n\geq1$. Let $\phi:V\rightarrow V$ a linear transformation for the which exist $v\in V$ such that $\{v,\phi(v),\phi^2(v),\ldots,\phi^{n-1}(v)\}$ is a base of $V$. Suppose that $U\subset V$, $U\neq\{0\}$ such that $\phi(U)\subset U$. Prove that exist $u\in U$ and that exist $m$ positive integer, such that $\{u,\phi(u),\phi^2(u),\ldots,\phi^{m-1}(u)\}$ is a base of $U$.

Note: Here $\phi^k(v)=\phi(\phi^{k-1}(v))$ for $k\geq2$.

Thank for some hints.

Comment: Any $u\in U\setminus\{0\}$ can be written as $\sum_{j=1}^{n} \alpha_j \phi^{j-1} (v)$, where the $\alpha_j$ are not all $0$. Take $u$ such that the highest $j$ for which $\alpha_j$ is non-zero is minimal.

Comment: Arnaud D. When you do reference the term "minimal", is for example, of I have  $u_1,\, u_2\in U-\{0\}$ in the form:                                                                                        $$u_1=\alpha_1 v+\alpha_2\phi(v)+\cdots+\alpha_s\phi^{s-1}(v)$$      and  $$u_2=\beta_1 v+\beta_2\phi(v)+\cdots+\beta_{\ell}\phi^{\ell-1}(v)$$,               with $s,\ell \leq n$. If $s<\ell$ then I choose $u_1$. Is corret?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. Sorry if I was unclear.